# What menu is called by Alt-Shift-S in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, menu

What menu is called by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> combination in Eclipse? How to call it from main menu? It is mostly resembles `Source` menu but has some differences.

[image]

**Source menu**

Source menu looks same but not exactly:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `Source` menu. If you do a right click in java editor you can see key combination for it and if you hover over `Source` you can see it is the same.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. If I rightclick over Source nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

About the visual difference: If it is invoked from the main menu, disabled menu items stay visible (but grayed), because you would be very confused if the vertical position of the same menu item changed all the time (depending on how many other menu items above are disabled).

Context menus on the other hand are invoked at arbitrary places of your screen, so you don't notice a certain menu item offset "jumping" relative to the complete context menu. That's why many menu items are not just disabled in the context menu, but set to *invisible*.

Answer (score 0):

That's the Source menu,  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Uppercase <kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: But what is the nature of it's difference from normal `Alt-S` which calls `Source` menu explicitly pulled down from main menu bar?